# PrimeFaces GMap - Drawing multiple polygons

Tags: google-maps, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a very simple question.

Is there a way to add multiple polygons to [PrimeFaces GMap](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/polygons.xhtml)?

If yes, can someone share a snippet/example?

If no, are there any alternatives to `GMap` in `JSF`?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence in the link you provided gives you the answer:

> Any number of polygons can be displayed on map.

I would do it the following way:

```
@ManagedBean
public class PolygonsView implements Serializable {

    private MapModel polygonModel;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        polygonModel = new DefaultMapModel();

        //Shared coordinates
        LatLng coord1 = new LatLng(36.879466, 30.667648);
        LatLng coord2 = new LatLng(36.883707, 30.689216);
        LatLng coord3 = new LatLng(36.879703, 30.706707);

        //Polygon
        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
        polygon.getPaths().add(coord1);
        polygon.getPaths().add(coord2);
        polygon.getPaths().add(coord3);

        polygon.setStrokeColor("#FF9900");
        polygon.setFillColor("#FF9900");
        polygon.setStrokeOpacity(0.7);
        polygon.setFillOpacity(0.7);

        polygonModel.addOverlay(polygon);
        //here it should be possible to add additional overlays
    }

    public MapModel getPolygonModel() {
        return polygonModel;
    }
}
```

The source code is also from the link you provided. Just create more Polygons and add them as overlay to your MapModel.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating the example @LarsBauer!
I never realized that MapModel can accept more than 1 polygons!
Now i'm realizing it was a silly question to ask!
Anyways, thanks alot, and Answer accepted! :)